# is there a way to make the zooming effect works?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make that when the user is hovering over the elements with the class `collectionWrapper`, the hovered element's height will become bigger. So I used things like this to make it
CSS:

```css
.collectionWrapper {
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-height: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 0px 5px 4px 4px;
  transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.collectionWrapper:hover {
  height: calc(calc(100vw - 1.6rem - 40px) / 5);
}
```

but then, somehow it won't expand when I hover on any of them, what I expected is it will expand its height into the one I want (the `calc(calc(100vw - 1.6rem - 40px) / 5)` part). I also tried to change the container of the element's height but it become even worse than the one I mentioned.

For Summary,
Expected:

- the height of the child element (collectionWrapper) should increase when hovering them

the result:

- nothing happens if there's too much child element inside (when total height > container size)

Codes associated with the question:
HTML:

```html
<div class="selectorBody flex row">
  <div class="selectorScroller">
    <div class="selectorList flex column" id="selectorList">
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor"><p>Something here</p></div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor"><p>Something here</p></div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor"><p>Something here</p></div>
      <!-- To save space, imagine here got a lot of things like above -->
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor"><p>Something here</p></div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor"><p>Something here</p></div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor"><p>Something here</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.selectorScroller {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.selectorList {
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100%);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.selectorList::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}
.selectorList::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: invisible;
  width: 5px;
}
.selectorList::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.selectorList:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: white;
}
.collectionWrapper {
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-height: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 0px 5px 4px 4px;
  transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.collectionWrapper:hover {
  height: calc(calc(100vw - 1.6rem - 40px) / 5);
}
.collectionWrapper:first-child {
  margin: 4px;
} 
.selectorBody {
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  height: calc(100% - 62px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 62px);
}
```

flex, and quaternaryColor are my shorthand styling, which is flex display and color respectively

if you're able to help, I really appreciate it

Comment: can you use transform: scale(XXX) instead of changing the height?

Comment: @pierfarrugia I don't think so, since in the future, the collectionWrapper's background will become the texture according to the folders containing the textures, if scale, it will makes the picture become stretched isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken you code and tried with come images in
image are in background, no-repeat, cover

I made one change in your css

```
calc(calc(100vw - 1.6rem - 40px) / 5)
```

to

```
calc((100vw - 1.6rem - 40px) / 5)
```

seems to work, perhaps I'm missing something!

```css
.selectorScroller {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.selectorList {
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100%);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.selectorList::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

.selectorList::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
  width: 5px;
}

.selectorList::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.selectorList:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: white;
}

.collectionWrapper {
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-height: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 0 5px 4px 4px;
  transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.collectionWrapper:hover {
  height: calc((100vw - 1.6rem - 40px) / 5);
}

.collectionWrapper:first-child {
  margin: 4px;
}

.selectorBody {
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  height: calc(100% - 62px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 62px);
}

.collectionWrapper:first-child {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/185/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/123/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/81/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(5) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/17/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(6) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/5/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(7) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/152/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(8) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/103/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(9) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/93/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(10) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/77/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(11) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/53/600/400");
}

.collectionWrapper:nth-child(12) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/37/600/400");
}
```

```html
<div class="selectorBody flex row">
  <div class="selectorScroller">
    <div class="selectorList flex column" id="selectorList">
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <!-- To save space, imagine here got a lot of things like above -->
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collectionWrapper quaternaryColor">
        <p>Something here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So far with the Run code snippet feature, I don't see any mistakes, I'll tell again when I tried in actual situation, if it works, I'll mark this as solution, thanks!

Comment: it works in Run Code Snippet but it doesn't work in my full code, I guess I'll update with my full code, though it'll be hard for answerer to read since I'm kinda bad in optimizing, or do you mind if I send you my full code in messaging then you update the final solution code here? If you don't mind, I will message you privately here

Comment: ok send me... I'll check if I can do something...